# Firebase - How do I add a new field for each row in an existing database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using real time Firebase database. Let's say I already have one million users and each user has fields like email, password, etc..

What if I suddenly want to add a new field to every user in my database? Like I want each user to have a field called age.

I know I can do it manually in Firebase but it's not practical when we deal with a large and complex database

Comment: While there is an accepted answer, I am not sure it's the *right* answer. Firebase *database* doesn't have fields - only key: value pairs and unlike SQL, there aren't pre-defined fields or columns. The child key: values (fields) are added on the fly. In general, FB doesn't allow nil/ empty values either, so adding a child field of *age* with no value (nil) will never be written. The only option there is to write a 0 value to the age key but then it's just extra data as nobody is 0. Better practice is to write data as you get it from the user.

Comment: If you really want to write a bunch of key: value pairs of age: 0, the accepted answer assumes firestore but really, it's a super simple task in Firebase. Just observe the users node with .childAdded and as the snapshot is read in, write out *age: 0* to that nodes key. Again though - it's probably better just to write the data when you actually have it; why write a million 0's to your users node when only 5000 users actually have logged in during the last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a method using Firebase .update running all documents?

Something like: (this is using Firebase firestore)

```
updateUser() {
        this.db.collection('yourDbCollection').doc('ifYourIdCostumized').update({
            age: newAgeHere
        })
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Document successfully updated!");
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error removing document: ", error);

            });
    }
```

Or you can use [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?hl=pt-br) if you want to make it server-side. Post some code so we can see how to help you.

Comment: yes but i need to delete this snippet of code after running it right? Cause it did the job and it's no longer necessary right?

Comment: Yeah, run only a time. ;) Or comment if you need add others properties in future.